# How do I aggregate rows in a column in a pandas datafame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame

| group_id | types | max_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ['a','b','c','d','e'] | 100 |
| 1 | ['b'] | 10 |
| 1 | ['d'] | 90 |
| 1 | ['e'] | 120 |

I need to create this data frame by aggregating the max values when they apply to each type.
In other word, the list [...] specify the default max value for each type, but each type can have an additional type that can override the default if it's less.

The result would be

| group_id | types | max_value | sub_values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ['a','b','c','d','e'] | 100 | [100,10,100,90,100] |

Because:

- 'a', 'c' keep the default value 100
- 'b' and 'd' have a value 10<100, so 10 is chosen
- 'e' has 120>100 so 100 is chosen

Answer (score 2):

Using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group_id': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'types': [['a','b','c','d','e'], ['b'], ['d'], ['e']],
                   'max_value': [100, 10, 90, 120]})
out = (df
   .explode('types')
   .sort_values(by=['group_id', 'types', 'max_value'])
   .drop_duplicates(['group_id', 'types'])
   .groupby('group_id', as_index=False)
   .agg(**{'types': ('types', list),
           'max_value': ('max_value', 'max'),
           'sub_values': ('max_value', list)
          })
)
```

Output:

```
   group_id            types  max_value               sub_values
0         1  [a, b, c, d, e]        100  [100, 10, 100, 90, 100]
```

Comment: This doesn't actually give the correct result - your `sub_values` list has `120` in it, which is wrong, it should be `[100,10,100,90,100]`. See the question and the other answers

Comment: @Nick Oops, that was my initial answer and I then simplified the code. It rolled back to my first answer ;)

Comment: If I have some time I'll compare the sort/drop dupes vs the groupby/groupby I used. It'd be interesting to know which was faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

- Use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for column "types" to get the list elements in separate rows.
- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `["group_id", "types"]` and apply a custom function (here called `get_val`) to column "max_value" to retrieve the correct value.
- Inside `get_val`, for each values in passed Series we subtract the first (i.e. "default") value, and check if the result is `<= 0` ([`Series.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html)). Now, we invert the Series (`[::-1]`) and use [`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) to get the index for the last `True`. We return the Series value at this position to retrieve the last value that is either equal to or less than the default value.
- Finally, we use another `df.groupby`, this time on 'group_id', and apply the aggregations for 'types' (`list`) and 'max_value' ('max' and 'list') ([`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)).

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'group_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}, 
        'types': {0: ['a','b','c','d','e'], 1: ['b'], 2: ['d'], 3: ['e']}, 
        'max_value': {0: 100, 1: 10, 2: 90, 3: 120}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_val(s):
    idx_val = (s - s.iloc[0]).le(0)[::-1].idxmax()
    return s[idx_val]

out = (
    df.explode('types')
    .groupby(['group_id', 'types'], as_index=False)['max_value']
    .agg(get_val)
    .groupby('group_id', as_index=False)
    .agg(
        types=('types', list),
        max_value=('max_value', max),
        sub_values=('max_value', list)
    )
)

out

   group_id            types  max_value               sub_values
0         1  [a, b, c, d, e]        100  [100, 10, 100, 90, 100]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two levels of groupby to achieve the result you want; first to find the minimum `max_level` for each `group_id` and `types` value, then to re-aggregate by `group_id` the `types` and `sub_level` values into lists and find the `max` of `sub_values`:

```
out = (df
    .explode('types')
    .groupby(['group_id', 'types'], as_index=False)
    .agg(sub_values=('max_value', min))
    .groupby('group_id', as_index=False)
    .agg(types=('types', list), max_value=('sub_values', 'max'), sub_values=('sub_values', list))
)
```

Output:

```
   group_id            types  max_value               sub_values
0         1  [a, b, c, d, e]        100  [100, 10, 100, 90, 100]
```